# Forcing a synchronous garbage collection in Ruby

Tags: ruby, swig, gdal

I am trying to use the GDAL bindings to create geographic datasets in a Ruby on Rails app. However, GDAL only flushes those datasets on disk when the corresponding Ruby objects are destroyed. This (unanswered) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509405/how-to-explicitly-close-datasets-in-gdal-ruby-binding) provides a nice explanation of what I am facing.

I tried setting every variable to `nil` and manually running `GC.start`, but as I understand it the Ruby GC is somewhat asynchronous (tell me if I'm wrong there, as I have limited Ruby experience), so this doesn't work all the time.

Is there a way to force a synchronous garbage collection so that I can be absolutely *certain* that my objects are destroyed when it is done?

*Note that I would vastly prefer using GDAL over other libraries, as I have a large existing Python codebase that also uses the GDAL bindings, and the Python to Ruby translation is (or should be) relatively painless.*

Comment: Can't you change the GDAL bindings a bit so that you can force the writing of datasets on disk? Ruby should allow it easily because from what you have described, I don't think there is a reliable way to do it. Meanwhile, you can easily make a method write_on_disk! and flag in some way that data is already written.

Comment: Hm, that's what I feared. Such a change sounds easy enough, it is just a pain to have to maintain a separate GDAL-Ruby version for that single purpose...

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, but there's a `sync_to_disk` method... which of course isn't implemented for the KML driver I'm using. :(